# Append not working when loading new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load data into a `div` using *JavaScript* when the page loads. I'm using *jQuery Mobile*. The page is called using normal `href`, which I assume gets hijacked into `ajax` by *jQM*.

But my JavaScript seems to behave somewhat strangely, all the script runs (I checked that using `alert`s), but the `append` function doesn't seem to have any effect on the page. I've tried all sorts of fuctions: `pagecreate`, `pagebeforeshow`, `document.ready`.

Here is relevant part of my code:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="content" style="padding:0" data-theme="k">      
        <ul class="rig columns-3" style="margin:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:8px;padding-top:20vw" id="DrinkGridView">        
            <!-- <li>
                <img src="images/logo.png" />
                <h3>Image Title</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            </li> -->   
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->         
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //$( document ).delegate("#page", "pageinit", function() {
        var global_id;
        var global_data;
        var fields = [];

        $.ajax({                    
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.1.120/yiibootstrap_old/index.php/userregistration/makedrink",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(obj, function() 
                {                           
                    fields.push({id:this['id'],name:this['name'],image:this['image'],Description:this['description']});            
                });
            var count = fields.length;                 
            count1 = parseInt(count);
            for (var r = 0; r < count1; r++)
            {
                $('#DrinkGridView').append('<a id="inline" href=#data><li id="' + fields[r]['id'] + '"> <img src="http://192.168.1.120/yiibootstrap_old/uploads/' + fields[r]['image'] + '"/> <h3><b>' + fields[r]['name'] + '</h3> <p id="sss">' + fields[r]['Description'] + '</p> </li></a>').children().last().trigger("create");
                // THIS APPEND IS NOT SHOWING RESULT !!
            }
        });
        //});    
    </script>   
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Comment: In your code ajax not properly close

Comment: it was closed, I just missed it when i removed some code for posting. The code runs with no errors but the apppend method doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Does the append work without `.children().last().trigger("create")`? Also put the `a` inside the `li` and not outside it.

Comment: Used the append code in my test pages with a bogus field. That works perfectly. Does your `fields` object contain any data?

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: Make sure its working "fields.push({id:this['id'],name:this['name'],image:this['image'],Description:this['description']});"

Comment: Yeah I checked the fields object and Yes it contains data.

Comment: Add `debugger` just below the `{` of the `success: function(data)` line. Open dev-tool by pressing F12 and refresh page. This will bring you into debug mode and you can watch your code step by step.

Comment: Is that page with `id=page` is the first page you load? or you navigate to from another page?

Comment: @omar i am navigating from another page using <a href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in `pagecreate` event delegated to page div with ID `page`. When page is created, target the listview within that page `$('#DrinkGridView', page)`. And then you need to call *refresh* method after appending elements `.listview("refresh")`.

`.children().last().trigger("create");` isn't the correct method to *enhance* listview.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page", function () {
    var $listview = $('#DrinkGridView', this), /* target listview */
        global_id,
        global_data,
        fields = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.1.120/yiibootstrap_old/index.php/userregistration/makedrink",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(obj, function () {
                fields.push({
                    id: this.id,
                    name: this.name,
                    image: this.image,
                    Description: this.description
                });
            });
            var count = fields.length;
            count1 = parseInt(count, 10);
            for (var r = 0; r < count1; r++) {
                /* add elements to $listview defined previously */
                $listview.append('<a id="inline" href=#data><li id="' + fields[r].id + '"> <img src="http://192.168.1.120/yiibootstrap_old/uploads/' + fields[r].image + '"/> <h3><b>' + fields[r].name + '</h3> <p id="sss">' + fields[r].Description + '</p> </li></a>');
            }
            /* refresh after for loops is done */
            $listview.listview("refresh"); /* refresh */
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: does the OP need to also add (data-role="listview") in ul

Comment: @omar. sould i place the javascript inside any specific div or anywhere would work?

Comment: @WhoDatDev place it in head. It will run once the target page is created and it will run only once.

Comment: @Omar. never mind. it worked superb. Thanks a lot. and can you give me any link to any simple resource(s) explaining all these page transition methods and functions. I'm new to HTML therefore the official documentation is above me.

Comment: @WhoDatDev you're welcome. Read more about page events http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: @omar. now the data loads but i'm getting an error : **Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'**

Comment: @WhoDatDev if it's a listview, add `data-role="listview"`. If it's something else, remove code line `.listview("refresh")`. Which widget are you trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

This code should function properly.

```
$('page').on('pageinit', function() {
    var global_id;
    var global_data;
    var fields = [];

    $.ajax({                    
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.1.120/yiibootstrap_old/index.php/userregistration/makedrink",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(obj, function() 
                {                           
                    fields.push({id:this['id'],name:this['name'],image:this['image'],Description:this['description']});            
                });
            var count = parseInt(fields.length);                 

            for (var r = 0; r < count; r++)
            {
                $('#DrinkGridView').append('<li id="' + fields[r]['id'] + '"><a id="inline" href=#data><img src="http://192.168.1.120/yiibootstrap_old/uploads/' + fields[r]['image'] + '"/> <h3><b>' + fields[r]['name'] + '</h3> <p id="sss">' + fields[r]['Description'] + '</p></a></li>').children().last().trigger("create");
                // Switched the a and the li, but that didn't prevent the code from working.
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In the posted code there was a `}` missing that should close the ajax success event. But I think that was just a copy paste error.

Comment: "_But my JavaScript seems to behave somewhat strangely, all the script runs (I checked that using alerts), but the append function doesn't seem to have any effect on the page._" not to mention `.ready()` should be used in jQM.